# Moving Controls Get placed on different Tab in TabControl

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Im working with VB 2010 In the form designer, trying to position some controls within a tab control.

Sometimes when I drag a control to position it, it gets placed on a different tab than the one I currently have selected and am working with. This is extremely annoying and seems to happen randomly. Does anyone else ever have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a major problem for you consider adding the controls manually in code.

Here's  a great tutorial on how to do so: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIEA3JSSAnw